# Is it possible to dispatch a svelte custom event with a target object?

Tags: svelte, custom-events

Is it possible to dispatch a svelte event (created with `createEventDispatcher`) with a target object like a native browser event?

I.e. receiving on the handler side `event.target.value` instead of event.detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but involve some hacking.

You can take a look into the svelte source code to see how event dispatching works. I'll outline the key parts as below.

Let's say we have two components, `Inner` and `Outer`.

```html
<!-- Inner.svelte -->
<script>
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher()
const dispatchFoo = () => dispatch('foo', 'bar')
</script>

<button on:click={dispatchFoo}>send</button>

<!-- Outer.svelte -->
<script>
import Inner from './Inner.svelte'
const handleFoo = (e) => { console.log('receive foo', e) }
</script>

<Inner on:foo={handleFoo}></Inner>
```

If you think about it, the event handler `handleFoo` is created in `Outer`, but it's actually register on `Inner`.

Check the compiled JS code you'll see:

1. `inner.$$.callbacks["foo"]` holds the event handler [[src](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/c7e820e08fade3b26e84de9025cd564bac87fbed/src/runtime/internal/Component.ts#L204)]
2. when you click the button and call `dispatch`, it just read the `inner.$$.callbacks["foo"]` for potential handlers, and if found, call them with `CustomEvent` as argument [[src](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/c7e820e08fade3b26e84de9025cd564bac87fbed/src/runtime/internal/lifecycle.ts#L30)]

The only way to set `customEvent.target` is by dispatch that custom event using `element.dispatchEvent(customEvent)`. But `element.dispatchEvent` is not used through the whole process.

### Solution (hack)

Write your own `createEventDispatcher`.

```js
import { get_current_component } from 'svelte/internal'

function createEventDispatcher() {
  const component = get_current_component();
  return (type, target, detail) => {
    const callbacks = component.$$.callbacks[type];
    if (callbacks) {
      const event = new CustomEvent(type, { detail });
      // the key is to call `dispatchEvent` manually to set `event.target`
      target.dispatchEvent(event);
      callbacks.slice().forEach((fn) => {
        fn.call(component, event);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c93cbf99a8ca4f44912e662a8e3cbef7?version=3.37.0)

Comment: Great elaboration on the subject. Yes, it's quite a hack, but with a lot of insights. Thanks!

Comment: One nice thing about svelte is that it compiles to plain old javascript. If you understand the internal, you can almost always hack your way around.

Answer (score 0):

Modified from hackape's answer

```js
import { get_current_component } from 'svelte/internal'

function createEventDispatcher() {
  const component = get_current_component(bubbles = true);
  return (type, target, detail) => {
    const callbacks = component.$$.callbacks[type];
    if (callbacks) {
      const event = new CustomEvent(type, { bubbles, detail });
      // the key is to call `dispatchEvent` manually to set `event.target`
      target.dispatchEvent(event);
      /* You have already raised an event, you should not repeat the callbacks to avoid duplication
        callbacks.slice().forEach((fn) => {
          fn.call(component, event);
        });
      */
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user5354671 Commenting out `fn.call(...)` wont invoke the callback on the outer component.

The `target.dispatchEvent()` only serves for the purpose of adding the target on that event object

Comment: Please, comment the answer of the user, don't publish it as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass the `target` explicitly:

```js
// Component.svelte
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte'
  const payload = 'foo'

  function onClick (event) {
    const { target } = event
    dispatch('myEvent', { target, payload })
  }
</script>

<button on:click={ onClick }></button>
```

And then, somewhere:

```js
<script>
  import Component from 'Component.svelte'

  function handler (event) {
    const { target, payload } = event.detail
  }
</script>

<Component on:myEvent={ handler }/>
```